# how to remove ubuntu from efi boot options

Tags: boot, uefi, system

I removed Ubuntu from the efi boot menu but it comes back

i already use easybcd but it still comes back

i try remove it manual from my efi bios but it still comes back

i already delete all of my linux partition(efi / swap)

and i already using efibootmgr via linuxmint

but still it comes back

its even worse
because after i use efibootmgr its change my windows efibootloader behavior

i use asus x401u amd c-60

*ubuntu 10.04.01(64bit)
already removed but still in my efi bootmenu

*win8pro (64bit)

i already follow this(but via linuxmint)
[How do I remove "Ubuntu" in the bios boot menu? (UEFI)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu/63613#63613(but) its still comes back
my problem similar like this
[ubuntu appears in BIOS menu (UEFI)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57056/ubuntu-appears-in-bios-menu/63607#63607)
and im gonna do this [I removed Ubuntu from the BIOS menu but it comes back](https://askubuntu.com/questions/219869/i-removed-ubuntu-from-the-bios-menu-but-it-comes-back) later

please help me

Answer (score 2):

Try mounting your EFI System Partition (ESP) and removing the `EFI/ubuntu` directory from that partition. Then boot a Linux emergency system in EFI mode and use `efibootmgr` to remove the Ubuntu entry. For instance:

```
# efibootmgr 
Timeout: 10 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0008,0006,0007
Boot0000* ubuntu
Boot0006* Hard Drive
Boot0007* CD/DVD Drive
Boot0008* INTERNAL EFI SHELL: ST32000542AS
# efibootmgr -b 0 -B
```

You'll need to modify the value passed to `-b` based on the initial `efibootmgr` output.