# Dual Boot: Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows8 Grub doesn't detect Windows and even Boot repair didn't work

Tags: installation, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows-8

I have installed windows 8 in the partition sda4 (and ubuntu 12.04 was pre-installed) - partition screenshot below - and then tried recommended repair using boot-repair. But after boot-repair, Grub does not detect Windows. I've tried to repair grub twice (using boot-repair), but no gain.

(Earlier I installed windows in logical partition but now, it is in primary then why it doesn't get detected by grub?)

[image: GParted screenshot]

So far I've tried these...

- Installed windows and later performed recommended-repair using LiveCD
- chrooted into the partition and update grub (following this https://askubuntu.com/a/88432/202806 )
- chrooted into the partition and installed grub and again updated it (following step 7 https://askubuntu.com/a/88432/202806 )

**Contents of `grub.cfg` - updated** (Please note that this file is in the directory `/boot/grub` and NOT in `etc/grub`. In fact, there is no such directory like `etc/grub`.)

http://pastebin.com/SUTFSBSL

Also, if it may be related to the problem in any way... Ubuntu does not show the 101GB (NTFS in which Windows is installed) partition in the devices and gparted shows an exclamation sign beside this particular partition, asking to run `chkdsk /f` on windows and rebooting twice (this was not shown while I was on LiveCD) but I am able to successfully mount this partition using terminal.

More info (if it may help with another question): Initially the /home was around 246GB and I shrank it to 146GB and installed windows in 100 GB (logical partition). 
Later when I got to know that windows won't boot from logical I managed to move that 100GB (after deleting it) out of extended by moving the 100GB unallocated space to bottom and decreasing the size of extended partition.

I installed windows in this (now) Primary partition and repaired grub. But grub didn't show windows loader option. So I again repaired windows boot loader. Now here I got two windows options, Windows 8 and windows 8 on volume6. The earlier is the option for the windows which I earlier installed when that was a logical drive. My (second - it is not related to Ubuntu though) question is why and how is windows boot loader is getting info about the previous installation of windows as I had deleted the partition later.

Comment: is that you can be able to boot both windows and ubuntu.

Comment: I want that, but I am unable to do so.

Comment: I am not saying that it's not the answer, I'm just saying that the ultimate purpose (of dual-booting) has not yet been met. Now I've made it a primary partition as you said but still can't dual-boot.

Comment: still you can't able to dualboot?

Comment: That's what I'm saying. I told so in that question also.

Comment: what was output of `sudo os-prober`?

Comment: I didn't check that. I'll try tomorrow and will report back.

Comment: `ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo os-prober
/dev/sda1:FreeDOS:FreeDOS:chain
/dev/sda2:Windows 8 (loader):Windows:chain
/dev/sda4:Windows 8 (loader):Windows1:chain
/dev/sda6:Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS (12.04):Ubuntu:linux
`

Comment: @AvinashRaj Sorry for delay in replying (I was experiencing problems making pendrive bootable). Could you please help me now.

Comment: which software did you use to create bootable usb?

Comment: I've made pendrive bootable now. Earlier LiLi was giving error, now I tried pendrivelinux's software. So it's not the issue now. I've posted the output of os-prober command to help you assist me.

Comment: i will be back within 15 minutes plz wait.And then it was better to start the discussion in chat,plz gain some rep.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11970/discussion-between-tarun-and-avinash-raj)

Comment: @Tarun If the Ubuntu install doesn't see that partition, then go ahead and do what `gparted` says. Run `chkdsk /f` on windows and reboot twice. (Yes I know you have to repair windows boot and then grub again, kinda boring) Gparted always flags NTFS partitions after moving/resizing them. If you do the `chkdsk` it will remove that flag, and it won't come back if you don't use gparted again on that partition. After that I advise you to repeat my procedure. It is clear from your `grub.cfg` that the installed ubuntu has no clue about that windows.

Comment: Also from your partition scheme it looks like you are using uefi boot. Can't you change in UEFI the OS which you want to boot?

Comment: When you install Windows it puts its boot files in the partition with the boot flag. It looks like sda2 or your recovery partition has the boot flag. Best move flag to sda4 and then rerun Windows repairs.

Comment: @oldfred Please explain this more. Can I just edit it using gparted in LiveCD without having any changes in the partition?

Comment: You can use gparted to move boot flag to the Windows partition. Right click edit flags. You can only have one boot flag per drive and it is for Windows, grub does not use boot flag. If using Windows it is the set active command. Then running repairs from Windows will add bootmgr & bcd to main Windows partition. If those files are in sda2 you may be able to copy them also to sda4. You may still need repairs from a Windows repair console.

Comment: @oldfred Here's what I did: Using LiveCD and Gparted, removed the boot flag from sda2 then added boot flag to sda4. Then using the the troubleshoot option (Command Prompt mode), executed these three commands `bootrec /fixmbr` `bootrec /fixboot` `bootrec /rebuildbcd`. After that again, using LiveCD, did `recommended-repair` using boot-repair. But I am still not getting Windows option in grub. Please let me know if I did anything wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This brought so much memory for me from the past which often happened to me.

The fix that worked for me: use your installation cd and start the system off from it.

Select the option from menu, "Rescue the broken system"

You will go through the cycle of series of questions which it would lead you to partition section.  When you arrive to that section, escape the process.  You then will see the menu and you should see "Install GRUB".

Re-install GRUB and be sure to install on your master HD (sda1)

Reboot

You will then see your GRUB back and it'll detect your dual OS between Win and Ubuntu.

EDIT:  Found this article for you: https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/tips#TOC-Make-Windows-the-first-option-in-the-Grub-boot-menu

Comment: The solution that you are giving (what I've understood) is to re-install grub. That's what boot-repair does! But it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I can't get from you question whether are you able to boot into ubuntu after you did a boot-repair from the Live CD? If you can do that, then do it. Then boot up the installed ubuntu system, and run `sudo update-grub` from the installed system. After that check whether you can boot into windows and ubuntu. If you can, problem solved, if you can't then update your question with your `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` from your installed ubuntu system.

Comment: There is no folder like grub. The only folder related to grub is `grub.d` but it does not have any file named `grub.cfg`. I found the file `grub.cfg` on searching the file system in `/boot/grub` whose contents have been added in the question.

Comment: @Tarun Of course. I missed typed it. Sorry.

Comment: I tried that `chkdsk /f`and gparted didn't show the exclamation sigh anymore (But it doesn't show it in the devices even now) but after doing that and updating grub, I still can't see windows loader option in grub.

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understand your UEFI OS selection advise. Could you please elaborate it a bit more.

Comment: @Tarun I was referring to [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/57134/221281) about the UEFI OS selection. So maybe it is possible to change which OS you want to boot in the UEFI firmware. (Although I have never seen this in practice, thats why I don't know whether it is possible.)

Comment: I'm very much sure that my hardware either doesn't support UEFI or it is disabled because when I tried to make fifth partition (actually I shrank sda5 and decreased its size by 100GB which I later created as partition by bringing it out of extended, as Avinash said), gparted threw an error saying only 4 Primary partitions can be there. Please corect me if I am wrong but what I've found, having read several of the questions and answers here is that UEFI supports more than 4 primary partitions to be created. I'll report back if I find anything in the Boot Options.

Comment: Just confirmed that it support UEFI but it is disabled by default in Boot Options.

Comment: @Tarun If oldred's solution does not work, you may try to change it to UEFI mode (of course with Secure boot turned off), and try installing in that mode. Unfortunately I have no more clue. :(

Comment: I tried his solution, but no gain yet. May I know what do you mean by `installing`? Sorry but I didn't get you.

Comment: @Tarun Installing the OS-s.

Comment: I'm sorry but if I could repartition it all, I would have done so earlier, but for some reasons I can't.